Help with loops – why is there an Ω?
I am just getting some experience with looping constructs in TeX/LaTeX.  I thought I understood how \@tfor works, and things were mostly coming out as I wanted.  But I ran into some unexpected behavior that I distilled into the MnWE below.
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\spaceToDot}[1]{\@tfor\x:=#1\do{\if\x .\else{\x}\fi}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\spaceToDot{ABC~DE}

\end{document}

The expected (by me) behavior of \spaceToDot is to replace every space character with a . and leave every other character untouched.  In its argument, I used a ~ so that the space would be registered by \@tfor which (as I understand it) normally just ignores spaces.
I have no idea why the output looks like this:

Where is this Ω coming from?!?
For that matter, I also don't understand why the space still appears; I thought that \if\x . would evaluate to just the . in this case.
Clearly, there's something I don't understand about the behavior of \@tfor (and/or that of \if).  If anyone can help by shedding some light on this, I would appreciate it tremendously!

\if expands tokens until it finds two non-expandable tokens. With \if~ you'll get in the end to \if\relax\unhbox\voidb@x [other stuff]. The \if evaluates to true, thereby using up the two primitives, and you are left with \voidb@x which is the register number 10, which in this context simply prints the glyph at slot 10 of the current font (an \Omega).

as Campa says, and for the other characters you are comparing each character to a . if it is true, removing it and if it is not true typesetting the character in {} (so breaking ligatures etc). Note \if\x . is  the same as \if\x.  There is no space token in the test.

Thank you, this is very helpful.  Clearly, my issues are with \if rather than with \@tfor!

What makes it difficult to write an answer is that is a bit of an XY problem. What is \spaceToDot supposed to do? Converting space tokens to dots might be more or less easy; but should it work also with ~ ?  Or only with ~ ? And what about consecutive spaces?

Well, aside from my issues with \if, I failed to recognize the ways in which ~ is not equivalent to just a space.  As it happens, what I really want to accomplish is to loop over some text and take one action for each non-space character, and some other action for each space (with each space in a run of consecutive spaces handled individually).  In fact, I was using ~ simply because \@tfor skips over space characters!  That latter issue is one I'm now hoping to handle, separately, later, once I figure out how to get \if working the way I want.

As confirmed in comments this is a bit of an XY problem, so let's address both.
The Y problem
Your current definition is doomed because with
\if\x .\else{\x}\fi

the space after \x is gobbled by the usual TeX rules, and you are in fact comparing... \x to the dot? No, not really, because \if expands tokens, and keeps expanding until it finds two unexpandable tokens. Therefore, if you feed a ~ to \if, the following happens:

\if~ finds the ~, which is an active character, i.e. a character which behaves as it were a control sequence;
the expansion of ~ leads to \if\ifincsname\expandafter~\else\expandafter\nobreakspace\fi;
we are not within a \csname...\endcsname, so the \else branch is chosen, and we have \if\nobreakpace;
\if keeps expanding, and the expansion of \nobreakspace leads to \if\protect\nobreakspace␣ (I'm using ␣ to indicate a space being part of the macro name);
in normal typesetting context \protect is \relax: this is the kind of unexpandable token which \if likes, but it is a single one, so \if keeps expanding to find a second one;
the expansion of \nobreaspace␣ leads to \if\relax\leavevmode\nobreak\␣;
\leavevmode is expandable, and its expansion leads finally to \if\relax\unhbox\voidb@x\nobreak\␣

Now \if sees two unexpandable primitives: \relax and \unhbox. By the rules of \if the comparison is true, and the corresponding branch is chosen. In the token stream there remains a stray \voidb@x. What is this? It is a permanently empty box register defined in the LaTeX kernel by \newbox\voidb@x, which after some steps results in \chardef\voidb@x=10. \voidb@x is therefore something like a shorthand for \char10. It can be used as number (which is the intended use), but in this case it occurs in normal typesetting, and then it simply prints the glyph in slot 10 of the current font, which for the standard font happens to be an uppercase Omega.
The X problem
In your last comment you say that you want to do something for characters which are not spaces, and something else for spaces, with consecutive spaces treated separately. This suggests a solution based on \obeyspaces
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\spaceToDot}{\begingroup\def\obeyedspace{.}\obeyspaces\spaceToDot@}
\newcommand*{\spaceToDot@}[1]{\spaceToDot@@#1\@@nil\endgroup}
\newcommand*{\spaceToDot@@}{}% better safe than sorry
\begingroup
   \obeyspaces
   \gdef\spaceToDot@@#1{\ifx#1\@@nil\else\ifx#1  \else\ifx#1~\obeyedspace\else(#1)\fi\fi\expandafter\spaceToDot@@\fi}%
\endgroup
\makeatother

\begin{document}

X\spaceToDot{this and  that but~this~ one~~too}X

\end{document}



The answer by campa is excellent with respect to the explanation of the bizarre character.
About 30 years ago, there was a similar issue with xy which sometimes printed an Omega as well.
How would I attack the problem nowadays? Not with \@tfor. In order to understand the code (which is otherwise easy) note that between \ExplSyntaxOn and \ExplSyntaxOff the character ~ stands for a space.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\spaceToDot}{om}
 {
  % store the input
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#2}
  % replace all space characters with periods
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl {~} {.}
  \IfNoValueTF {#1}
   {
    % no optional argument, print
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
   }
   {
    % optional argument, store
    \tl_new:N #1
    \tl_set_eq:NN #1 \l_tmpa_tl
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\spaceToDot{ABC DE}

\spaceToDot[\foo]{ABC DE}

\texttt{\meaning\foo}

\end{document}


The optional argument should be a control sequence (still undefined) which will be defined as the replaced text.
A more complex solution where also ~ is translated to a dot. The main problem is that at the document level ~ is active, so a trick is used.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\spaceToDot}{om}
 {
  \deaett_spacetodot:n {#2}
  \IfNoValueTF {#1}
   {
    \tl_use:N \l__deaett_tmp_tl
   }
   {
    \tl_new:N #1
    \tl_set_eq:NN #1 \l__deaett_tmp_tl
   }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__deaett_tmp_tl
\tl_new:N \l__deaett_tilde_tl

\tl_set:Nn \l__deaett_tilde_tl {X}
\regex_replace_once:nnN {X}{\cA\~} \l__deaett_tilde_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \deaett_spacetodot:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__deaett_tmp_tl {#1}
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__deaett_tmp_tl {~} {.}
  \tl_replace_all:NVn \l__deaett_tmp_tl \l__deaett_tilde_tl {.}
 }
  

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\spaceToDot{ABC DE~FG}

\spaceToDot[\foo]{ABC DE~FG}

\texttt{\meaning\foo}

\end{document}


